# push() won't work as expected in reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Why doesn't `a.push(b)` work in my `Array.reduce()? a=a.push(b)` where `b` is a string, turns `a` to an integer.?!

```
 getHighestValuesInFrequency: function(frequency) {
 //Input:var frequency = {mats: 1,john: 3,johan: 2,jacob: 3};
 //Output should become ['John','jacob']

var objKeys = Object.keys(frequency);
var highestVal = objKeys.reduce((a,b)=>
            {highestVal = (frequency[b] > a)? frequency[b] : a;
             return highestVal;},0);

var winner = objKeys.reduce((a,b)=>
      { a = (frequency[b] === highestVal)? a.push(b) : a;
        return a},[]);

return winner;  
 }
```

Comment: *"The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array."* - the docs.

Answer (score 27):

Since `push()` returns the new length of the array, you're assigning the length to `a`. Instead of a conditional operator, use an `if` statement.

```js
var winner = objKeys.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (frequency[b] === highestVal) {
        a.push(b);
    }
    return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 9):

The push() returns the new length. You can use ES2015 spread syntax:

```
var winner = objKeys.reduce((a, b)=> {
    a = (frequency[b] === highestVal)? [...a, b] : a;
    return a
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the excellent answer by @Alexander Moiseyev.

You can avoid setting and mutating both variables `a` and `winner` by doing the following:

```
return objKeys.reduce((acc, val) =>
    frequency[val] === highestVal 
      ? [...acc, val] 
      : acc
,[])
```

note: for clarity I have explicitly declared the accumulator and value in this reduce method.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this structure you provide is not clear enough

I would use instead an array of objects each having a name and a frecuency

```
var frequencies = [{name : "mats", frecuency : 1},
                   {name : "john", frecuency: 3},
                   {name : "johan", frecuency: 2},
                   {name : "jacob", frecuency: 3}];
```

Then you can use a filter operation and map to get what you need

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, frequencies.map(function(o){return o.frecuency;}));
var maxElems = frequencies.filter(function(a){return a.frecuency == max}).map(function(a){return a.name;});
```

`maxElems` will give you the names of the people with higher `frecuency`

Answer (score 0):

**The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) enables an even shorter way:**

```
const winner = objKeys.reduce((a, b) => {
  return frequency[b] === highestVal ? [...a, b] : a 
}, [])
```